# data twice formula text in cell

Tags: sharepoint, formula, duplicates

In SharePoint I have an IF formula based on values in another column.  The text is output twice in the "Standard View," but not in "Datasheet View."  I have found that if I have numbers and I specifically output the data as a number it does not do this.  However, I am working with text and cannot find any way to get it to show correctly.

For example, if my formula output is OK.  It will show as OKOK, but only in the standard view.

Version 2007; Formula:

```
 =IF(
   ISNUMBER(FIND("A",Category)),
   "For Review",
   IF(
     OR(
         ISNUMBER(FIND("B",Category)),
         ISNUMBER(FIND("S",Category)),
         ISNUMBER‌​(FIND("F",Category))
     ),
     "For Info",
     "Not Issued to Customer"
   )
 )
```

Comment: Please add your formula.  What version of SharePoint?

Comment: Version 2007; Formula:  =IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("A",Category)),"For Review",IF(OR(ISNUMBER(FIND("B",Category)),ISNUMBER(FIND("S",Category)),ISNUMBER(FIND("F",Category))),"For Info","Not Issued to Customer"))